# How to use a path with spaces in it as an env var?

Tags: mac, terminal

I am on a Mac and I am trying to use environment variables as a reference holder to run commands.

For example, I have a file with a path like so:

> /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/Info.plist

I'm trying to read it with the cat command. From this [SO question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94679/how-do-cope-with-a-space-when-setting-the-path), I can either use a backslash or quotes to use that path, like so:

> cat /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/Info.plist

or

> cat "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/Info.plist"

Fantastic!

However, say I export the path as an env var, using export:

> export AS_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents"

and then I want to read the Info.plist file using the env var:

//Restart or refresh terminal settings

> source ~/.profile
>
> cat $AS_HOME/Info.plist

This is throwing an error where it doesn't understand the path. I've tried setting the env var both ways (one with quotes and the other using backslahses). When I use the echo command with that env var, it prints out fine..

Any thoughts/work arounds on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cat "$AS_HOME/Info.plist"` should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You're learning one of the first rules of safe shell scripting: Always quote your paths that contain variables. So your last example line should be:

```
cat "$AS_HOME/Info.plist"
```

Note that double-quotes allow dollar-sign expressions to still be expanded, while most other special character meanings are escaped (ignored). Single-quotes wouldn't work here because they escape dollar-sign expressions.